# How to create an email adress from with a name and surname?

Tags: google-apps-script

I try to create an email adress from a name and surname.
Ex: Tom Coulomb => tom.coulomb@email.com

Here is my code:

```
var emailValideur = sheetform.getRange(i, 12).getValue().replace(/" "/g,".");
 emailVa`enter code here`lideur = emailValideur + "@email.com";
 sheetform.getRange(i,38).setValue(emailValideur);
```

Do I use the ".replace()" correctly?

Comment: bear in mind edge cases such as double family names with spaces. e.g. Tom Coulomb Jones. should that be `tom.coulomb.jones` or `tom.coulombjones`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the js code that you should adapt

```
 str = "Tom Coulomb"
 str = str.replace(/ /g,".")+"@gmail.com"

 // Tom.Coulomb@gmail.com
```